# $((x+2)^2 - (x+1)^2) - ((x+1)^2-x^2) = 2$ Is this proof valid for this identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

Claim:
$$((x+2)^2 - (x+1)^2) - ((x+1)^2-x^2) = 2$$

Proof:

$$x \times x = x^2$$
$$(x+1) \times x = x^2 +x$$
$$(x+1) \times (x+1) = x^2 + x + (x+1)$$
$$(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$$

As we know, $2x+1$, is the definition of an odd number, since an odd number is always one more than a multiple of $2$.

$$(x+1)^2 - x^2 = 2x+1$$

The difference between two **consecutive** odd numbers will always be $2$, like e.g. $3-1 =2$, $5-3 = 2$, $7-5 = 2$, and so on.

Therefore:

$$((x+2)^2 - (x+1)^2) - ((x+1)^2-x^2) = 2$$

Is this proof valid? Also, have you ever seen this proof before? Has the same identity been proven in a different, better way?

Comment: Since $(x+2)^2-(x+1)^2=2x+3$ , $2x+3-(2x+1)=2$ yes

Comment: Are you not allowed to simply expand the LHS to get what you want?

Comment: Note that using the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ you would get straightaway $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$. Your proof is correct if $x$ is restricted to integers. For non-integral $x$, the statement is still true but not the bit regarding odd numbers since $2x+1$ is not necessarily odd.

Comment: The way that you have written, you are assuming $x$ to be an integer, it remains valid for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @LightYagami I see, I completely forgot about the fact that x could be a non-integer.

Comment: @LightYagami Furthermore, as $x$ cancels, for any superset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's evaulate
$$((x+2)^2 - (x+1)^2) - ((x+1)^2-x^2) $$
using the difference of $2$ squares factorisation:
$$((x+2)^2 - (x+1)^2) - ((x+1)^2-x^2) =(x+2+x+1)(x+2-x-1)-(x+1+x)(x+1-x)$$
$$=(2x+3)-(2x+1)=3-1=2$$
as required.